# HTTP Header problem

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4. I have created one pdf and displaying in a new window. After I displayed the pdf when I click on other links I got the below kind of code. I think it showing my html source file.

How to resolve this problem?

> 141070HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 13
>   Apr 2011 13:22:07 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63
>   OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1
>   mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4 Expires: Thu,
>   19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=94
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   ... ... ...

This is my symfony code to display pdf.

```
    $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public', true);
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Expires', 0);
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Length', filesize($path));
    $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo readfile($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where does `141070` come from? It's the first that is sent to the client, and it should be `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` that triggers HTML rendering.

The client probably don't know what to do with the data and therefor render it directly.

Comment: I understood. But I dont know where it is coming from. I have using symfony. I just rendering the another page by clicking tab. Can you tell me where exactly it comes from?

Comment: Please post all header rows you are receiving. I have never worked with Symphony so I can't say how it renders it's output. I would have guessed that you can't modify headers like that from symphony. Have you checked you response content using any inspection tool? FireBug, fiddler? Wireshark? tcpdump?